# MYSQL where not null for at least one column

Tags: mysql, where-clause, notnull

There is a cross join table needs to capture rows with at least one `not null` value for specific columns:

```
where books.id is not null 
or typings.id is not null
or translates.id is not null
```

is there any function or method to prevent duplicate `not null` in that where clause?

something like this :
`where at_Least_not_Null_One_Of(books.id,typigns.id,translates.id)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
COALESCE(books.id,typigns.id,translates.id) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks, and which one is  faster ? multiple `where` clause or `COALESCE`?

Comment: @alex You can `explain` these two queries and check the performance.